# How can I make a string variable contain a single character "\" in python?

Tags: python-3.x, eol

```
string="\"
```

**This give error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal**

**srring=r"\" also not working**

Answer (score 2):

You could write it like this:

```
string="\\"
```

The first escapes the latter and prevents it from escaping the end of the literal.

---

Second question from the comments:

Write a function like this one:

```
def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]
```

then go and call it with your string:

```
s=r"w:/a\bc::/12\xy"
find(s, "\\")
```

which will print

> [4, 12]

Comment: But string will print "\\" not "\"

Comment: I have to store index of "\" in  s=r"w:/a\bc::/12\xy". How can I do that"?

Comment: No, it will not. Please go ahead and try it.

Comment: ah. mind your 'r' in front of the string. You are dealing with raw strings. those are different.

Answer (score 0):

Just double up the backslash:

```
inp = "Jon\\Skeet"
print(inp)
```

This prints:

```
Jon\Skeet
```

The issue here is that backslash is a control character, and `\"` appearing inside a string delimited by double quotes means a literal double quote.

If you want to *split* the above string by backslash, then use `split()`:

```
parts = inp.split("\\")
print(parts)

['Jon', 'Skeet']
```

Comment: I have to store index of "\" in  s=r"w:/a\bc::/12\xy". How can I do that

Comment: What is your actual end goal here?

Comment: currently, I am solving a problem which demands to split string when it encounters "\"